# Flask: Should my own configuration be added to app.config?

Tags: python, flask, config

Consider a Flask app which imports a configuration class that generates a configuration from a file (YAML, in this example):

```python
from config import ConfigGenerator
app = Flask(__name__)
```

**What is the right place for the configuration object in a Flask app?**

Should it be in the module namespace:

```python
config = ConfigGenerator('/etc/server/config.yaml')
```

Or in the `app.config`:

```python
app.config['my_config'] = ConfigGenerator('/etc/server/config.yaml')
```

Or even directly under `app`:

```python
app.myconfig = ConfigGenerator('/etc/server/config.yaml')
```

I think that all three options would work, but I wonder if there are any style or Flask-specific considerations to take into account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first two options are not much different, other than you now don't have to import your config object separately. In other words, by using `app.config` you can access the configuration throughout your Flask app wherever you already have access to `current_app`.

The last option however should not be used, don't add attributes to the Flask object.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "don't have to import your config object separately". I think I have to `from config import ConfigGenerator` anyhow.

Comment: @AdamMatan: yes, in your main file. But if you use separate modules in your Flask app, then those separate modules can now access `current_app.config['my_config']`.